# How to take the sum of some, but not all, ints in an array

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array and I want to be able to take the sum of certain integers in the array. It will always be the first 2, first 3, or first 4 elements so it won't be taking the first and last integers, if that makes it any easier.

I tried this code, but can't find a way to stop it before it sums all the integers in the array:

```
let x = array.reduce(0, +)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `prefix` method.

```
let nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let sum = nums.prefix(3).reduce(0, +)

print(sum) // 6
```

> If you pass to prefix a value greater than `nums.count`, the prefix will automatically return the entire array.

```
nums.prefix(10).reduce(0, +) // 15
```

Answer (score 1):

Try slicing the array:

```
// array[lowerBound..<upperBound] ignore upperBound
// array[lowerBound...upperBound] include upperBound

// Examples:

// Change 2 for the starting index you want to include
array[2..<array.count].reduce(0,+)

array[0..<array.count-2].reduce(0,+)

// Be careful with upper/lower bounds
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that sums up the elements of an array of `Int`s between the given indexes (inclusive, indexing start from 0):

```
let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
func sumUpRange(numbers:[Int], from:Int, to:Int)->Int{
    return numbers.enumerated().filter({ index, num in index >= from && index <= to}).map{$0.1}.reduce(0,+)
}
sumUpRange(numbers: numbers, from: 1, to: 3)  //output is 2+3+4=9
```